# Why when upgrade gearman python package from 'gearman(2.0.2)' to 'gearman3(0.2.0)', sometimes job missed and delayed

Tags: python, gearman

We often used the following code to connect to gearman server to get job:

```
gm_worker = gearman.GearmanWorker(['localhost:4730'])
gm_worker.set_client_id('xxxworker')
gm_worker.register_task(b'xxx', func1)
gm_worker.work()
```

With python 2.7.18 and gearman package 'gearman(2.0.2)' installed, the code worked.

As python 2 is runing to the end of lifetime, we upgrade to python 3.6 and installing gearman python package 'gearman3(0.2.0)'. From then on, job sometimes missed, sometimes delayed no more than 10 seconds.

Now we have 2 worker,one for python 2.7.18 and gearman package 'gearman(2.0.2)', still working, but with limited python 2 time span; another for python 3.6 and gearman python package 'gearman3(0.2.0)', job sometimes missing and sometimes delayed.

Till now, we cannot find the cause.

Can somebody help?

Or are there any similar job server like gearman?

```
                                        Many Thanks!
                                        Howard
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be good to address the question to the maintainer of `python3-gearman`? https://github.com/josiahmwalton/python3-gearman/issues

Comment: We use https://github.com/wcgallego/pecl-gearman, but that's no longer being maintained. It works though. :)

Comment: Thanks.man. Because gearman is not under development. maybe we should change to another similar server. can you recommend some similar server which can fan out lots of jobs to some workers.

Comment: I think you are conflating the Gearman PHP library with the gearmand server. The latter is certainly actively maintained at github.com/gearman/gearmand. (I’m one of the maintainers.)